# Отправка файла пользователю Django

Tags: python, django, файлы

Мне нужно отправить файл пользователю в качестве ответа. У меня получается сделать это с помощью следующего кода:

```
data = open(path_to_file, "br").read()
response = HttpResponse(data, "application")
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={os.path.basename(object_file.pathToFile)}'
return response
```

Однако он просто отправляет пользователю файл, а надо сделать так, чтобы началась загрузка.

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка выполняется через Фронтенд - грубо говоря, это не ваша проблема, если вы бэкендер. И при этом, отправлять файл не нужно вовсе - можно просто вернуть ссылку на этот файл, и на [фронте](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_download.asp) загружать